# Typescript assigning string value to color in css

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to make color as dynamic, so I am using useState to manage the string value.

```
const [myColor, setmyColor] = useState<string>("#FFFFFF")

<div style={{ color: {myColor} }} />
```

this gives me TS error as string not able to assign to string.

However, I got string in my useState, and color is taking string as params.

I am confused here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is

```js
<div style={{ color: myColor }} />
```